# replacing character from file with php

Tags: php

I have a script that is supposed to download a file, do a search/replace of a character in my file but it's not working.  It's supposed to find the > and a space and replace it with nothing, basically just deleting those 2 characters.  It looks like it downloads and reads the file and outputs the new file, but without the search/replace.  What am I missing?  (Yes, the space after the > is intentional)

```
//download file
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $filename);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch); 
curl_close ($ch);
    $destination = "./temp/export.csv";
    $file = fopen($destination, 'w+');
    fputs($file, $data);
    fclose($file);

$cleanedup = "./temp/export-clean.csv";
$input = fopen($destination, 'r');
$output = fopen($cleanedup, 'w+');

while (!feof($input)) {
$line = fgets($input);

$parsed = str_replace('> ', '', $line);

fputs($output, $parsed);
}
fclose($input);
fclose($output);
```

Here's a sample file: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=38994668603289072431

Comment: Can you provide a sample file so that it can be tested?

Comment: Maybe it's really `&gt;` but you haven't shown any input or output.

Comment: Added a sample file to the original post.  The export and the export-clean come out to be the exact same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasted code works, but there is not `'> '` substring in provided data.
Maybe you wanted to eliminate `'< '` substring, probably in a bit safer way like this

```
$parsed = str_replace(',< ', ',', $line);
```

Comment: OMG, I'm an idiot!  Thanks...yes, you're right, I totally biffed and used the > instead of <.  Can you please explain how you think your version is "safer"?

Comment: By looking in your CSV file, I guess you are trying to remove < in the beginning of column H. Theoretically, if for example column G contains string instead of YELLOW something like A < B, the char < will be removed as well. So my version will remove only beginning < (starting column B)